# How can I create Coinbase oauth application on behalf of the user?

Tags: coinbase-api

I have the following goal - I want to integrate my application users with Coinbase. All users should be able to connect their own Coinbase accounts with my application so I can grant read permissions. In order to do that I have to use oauth api, but the problem is, I do not want to ask users to first create oauth application through the Coinbase UI themselves and then provide me the application ID and secret so I can initiate a coinbase oatuh integration. I need a seamless, one click integration. Do you have any suggestions how to achieve that?
Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of oAuth to not need the api key.

this is the documentation that says how to do it.  future questions need to be programming specific or stack overflow will eat you up for dinner.

https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/sign-in-with-coinbase/docs/sign-in-with-coinbase-integration